# What does "Med." as a style mean in jazz fake books?

Tags: terminology, jazz, tempo

I imagine it stands for "medium", but is it a tempo indication or does it mean something else/more? For example, how does `(Med. Bossa Nova)` differ from `(Bossa Nova)`? Some pieces also only have `(Med.)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a tempo marking. There's no strict definition, but a medium tempo is often in the range of ~100-150 bpm.

The marking `Med. Bossa Nova` means to play a bossa nova groove/style at a medium tempo. The Bossa Nova groove doesn't always have to be played at medium tempo. For example, check out [this fast version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iZRNT_IfNl8) of Girl From Ipanema, which is *usually* played at a medium tempo. A song in a jazz Real Book with just `Med` (and no accompanying groove like `Bossa Nova`) will usually be played as a swing.

Comment: Just to follow up on some valuable discussion in other comments, a lack of tempo marking doesn't always imply `Med.` tempo. If a song is commonly played at two different tempos, it might not have a tempo marking when written up in the real book.

Comment: I've not come across 'med' as meaning swing. Surely 'med' refers to tempo - as in your answer - but swing is feel, not tempo.

Comment: possibly: medio tiempo

Comment: @Tim, I agree completely! In the last paragraph, I'm basically saying that if the feel isn't marked, swing is a good bet :)

Answer (score 3):

Just 'medium'.   Meaning just as much (or just as little) as 'medium' ever does.  A bit like putting 'mf' as a dynamic.   (Except that some dynamic IS required at the start of a piece, a qualifier such as 'medium' isn't.)

Comment: So in the case of `(Med. Bossa Nova)`, what does it tell me about the piece that `(Bossa Nova)` doesn't?

Comment: The tempo suggestion.

Comment: That it isn't specially fast or slow.  Or very little. I thought I made that clear in my answer?

Comment: If there was no `Med`, I'd also assume that it's not specially fast or slow. That's why I found it weird that sometimes it's specified and sometimes it isn't.

Comment: Yeah.  Not the weirdest thing jazz guys do, but weird.

Comment: So, basically, a piece with 'med' will be played pretty well like a piece with no marking..?

Comment: @Tim well, talking strictly about real/fake books, the original real books put a tempo marking when there really was a classic tempo for the tune, and it might sound bit odd to deviate too far from it (though we still do of course!). Many do not have tempo markings and this isn’t to say they are all Med, but they tend to have a wider range of what would be considered ‘normal performance tempos’. Eg Stella by Starlight is commonly nearing a ballad, a burner or comfortably in between, and is given no marking. The newer real books tried to give a tempo marking to every song.